# Django url pattern regex to pass a email as a parameter in the url

Tags: python, regex, django

I am writing a view which is accepting a email as parameter passed by url like

```
url(r'^admin/detail_consultant_service/((?P<consultant_id>\[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}))/$',
            'admin_tool.views.consultant_service_detail', name="consultant_service_detail"),
```

And here is the content of my template

```
{% for consultant in list_consultants %}
    <li>
        {{consultant.id}}
        <a href="{% url consultant_service_detail consultant.id %}">{{ consultant|disp_info }}</a> <br/>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

BUt When I am accessing the url I am getting the error

```
everse for 'consultant_service_detail' with arguments '(u'rahul183@gmail.com',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Please help me out What I am doing wrong in my regex why it is not accepting this mail .Is this the problem or something else ?

Comment: You're escaping the opening bracket for the character class here `\[A-Z0-9._%+-]` remove the backslash

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are passing a positional argument instead of a keyword argument. The following should work:

```
{% url consultant_service_detail consultant_id=consultant.id %}
```

Also if you are using Django>=1.5 you should use the `url` as follows:

```
{% url 'consultant_service_detail' consultant_id=consultant.id %}
```

And since that is a new behavior, you can actually (which is recommended) use in in earlier versions of Django (I think >=1.3) by:

```
{% load url from future %}
{% url 'view_name' ... %}
```

The regex I think is fine according to [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) so the problem is most likely with the definition itself. Try this:

```
url(r'^admin/detail_consultant_service/(?P<consultant_id>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$',
    'admin_tool.views.consultant_service_detail',
    name="consultant_service_detail"),
```

so a valid url will be similar to:

```
foo.com/admin/detail_consultant_service/email.address@here.com/
```

Comment: I am using django 1.3 no change in the result

Comment: Reverse for 'consultant_service_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'consultant_id': u'rahul183@gmail.com'}' not found.

Comment: Then the error is either in the regex or the url is not properly registered.

Comment: Try manually going to the url and see if Django recognizes it.

Comment: When I am passing the url and accepting the consultant_id in request.GET it is executing properly I dono y it is not working for above url

Comment: @HamZa I actually removed it in my answer.

Comment: @miki725 lol, I see something very lame now ... How in the world will that regex match a lower string email address ?

Comment: `(?P<consultant_id>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})`

Comment: @HamZa  you are really a great man Thanks for backing me on track

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one application in a project, which is most likely the case here, your url should be namespaced. The url in the template should be in this format as explained [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/)

```
{% url 'My-App-Name:my-url-name' args or kwargs %}
```

Hence your code shoul look like this,

```
{% url 'Your-app-Name:consultant_service_detail' consultant_id=consultant.id %}
```