# How to allow "@" in django urls?

Tags: django, django-urls

I'd like user to be able to choose at sign `@` as well as alphanumeric and hyphen in their username. However this leads to 404 in the relevant regexp:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.-]+)/$', 'userprofile.views.profile'),
```

I tried `[\w.-@]` and `[\w.-\@]` but none worked.

How to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django url pattern regex to pass a email as a parameter in the url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429088/django-url-pattern-regex-to-pass-a-email-as-a-parameter-in-the-url)

Comment: @Brandon not quite the same question, as I don't want to limit the usernames to be emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question states nothing about email addresses, just wanting `@` symbols in usernames, and this should suffice:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w@\d-]+)/$', 'userprofile.views.profile'),
```

The relevant bit is: `[\w@\d-\.]+`, which matches at least one of any word character, an `@` symbol<sup>*</sup>, any digit, a hyphen or a dot.

<sup>* [The `@` symbol is the only character on a standard 101 keyboard to not have a name!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_sign)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately I still get: `NoReverseMatch at /profile/@@@/` and `NoReverseMatch at /profile/p@q/` among other creative uses of `@` :(

Comment: Turned out that the user profile had not been created due to previous error in url rendering. Your regexp is perfectly fine expect it need a `.` to accout for dotted names. Please add that and I'll accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make the `@` optional. This pattern will catch most email-like strings.

```
(?P<username>[-\w]+(?:\@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:\.)?[A-Za-z]{2,4})
```

If you want to catch something like `a@a` you will need to make everything after, and including the period optional:

```
(?P<username>[-\w]+(?:\@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?)?
```

That pattern will match:

```
foo@bar.com
foo@bar
foobar
```

Comment: You would have to make everything including and after the period optional

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean.

Comment: I've added an additional example.

Comment: alas I still get `NoReverseMatch at /profile/@@@/` and `NoReverseMatch at /profile/a@a/`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why you would want `@@@` in your username, however, @Lego Stormtroopr's RegEx does indeed work, and is simpler. I was wrongly assuming that you were going with two basic pattern types - emails and/or usernames